# Serving static media directly from heroku with Django

Tags: django, heroku, django-tinymce

Due to not being able to store TinyMCE js files on my S3 bucket due to origin problems i'm trying to get Heroku to serve them up.

Here's what I've attempted so far but no luck. The browser url looks good (http://www.mysite.com/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js) but heroku doesn't serve them up and returns a 404.

Here's my code:

Settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
TINYMCE_JS_URL = MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce'
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns += patterns('',
       (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_URL}))
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
       (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I can serve static assets directly from heroku using following code:

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
TINYMCE_JS_URL = MEDIA_URL + 'js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'js/tiny_mce'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
)
```

base.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    forced_root_block: false,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    force_br_newlines : true,
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it working using the comments in a github discussion https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/pull/15

Primarily I changed the urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns += patterns('',
       (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': '/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce/static/'}))
```

I've got a feeling this could be much better resolved but i'm out of ideas and this works

Answer (score 0):

For Django >= 2.0.0, For serving `MEDIA_URL` directly from heroku you can use

```
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
from django.views.static import serve


urlpatterns = [
...
re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,
        kwargs=dict(document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)),
]
```

Remember, heroku removes MEDIA_ROOT folder with every deploy.

More info
https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted